# Microsoft Exchange 2016 Wont receive internal emails

Tags: exchange

I have successfully set up a fresh Microsoft Exchange 2016 inside a test environment; additionally, I have also successfully connected exchange to outlook.

My problem is that when I send emails, they will not appear in a users inbox.

I have set up send connector with "*" as plenty of tutorials suggest, and all of the receive connectors are default

I am sending email from user1@domain.com to user2@domain.com, keep in mind that this is all internal and no external use of public dns (godaddy, netsolutions) has been implemented yet.

Please help,

Mike

Comment: OK, we are going to need more info to help you. When you send the email you end up with a copy of the email in either the Sent items folder or the outbox. If it is in the outbox, then Outlook is not properly configured to send or Exchange is not properly configured to receive. If the message ends up in the sent folder then the message was handed off to Exchange. So lets start with that. When you hit send, does a copy of the email end up in the sent folder or the outbox?

Answer (score 0):

so to answer your question

Yes, the mail does end up in “sent items” on my outlook.

It does appear that the messages are handed off to exchange, but this is weird since another user on my domain can’t receive email from another user on the domain.

Could the receive connectors be configured improperly then?

The receive connectors were never changed from their default value.

Could this be an internal dns issue ?

Thank you

Comment: then Outlook did its job, so exchange must not be routing the message. This means the receive connector is also good. You may be right about DNS. The DNS server needs 2 things, it must be aware of the domain and aware of exchange. Does it have an MX record? And if it is not a domain controller then does it know how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

after reading your reply I did some things:

On DNS: 
I added an MX Record (Points to Exchange Server IP)

> mail.domain.com

On DNS: I added CNAME (Points to mail.domain.com)

> autodiscover.domain.com

On DNS: I added HOST (A) (Points to Exchange Server IP)

Now on the Exchange Admin Panel (ECP)

I went to SERVERS->EDIT->DNS LOOKUPS-> INTERNAL DNS LOOKUPS

I switched it from all network adapters to my internal adapter.

It now shows AD and my routers IP in Address box.

I did this because I was unsure if the machines were communicating, but still no luck.

The mail still doesn’t come to the users inbox, could I be missing some key steps in configuration? Specifically, right after Exchange finished its installation

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Excellent, those are all important records. So I'm wondering where does this message end up? Stuck in the Queue? Can you send yourself an email? That is, from user1 to user1? Does OWA work? Can you send receive from OWA? Have you run Test-Mailflow on the Exchange console? Are the system and application logs on the exchange server clean? Send an email with a unique subject line and then run a message trace. Does EX2016 have a BPA? I don't remember. Use telnet to send mail and pay attention to the response from exchange. Exchange uses AD for internal routing, the problem is between these two.

Comment: Hi Larry, sorry I was busy this last day. Funny thing happened, some messages did make to inbox, but there was actually a huge delay time. OWA does work, but sending and receiving emails does not work properly there either. I ran the "Test-Mailflow" and received "TestMailFlowResult: Failure"

Comment: Quick update. I saw that mailflow was working, in-fact I was sending a receiving email messages for a solid 5 minutes; however, at this point in time mail flow is taking a long time to send. I believe DNS is ok, but do you have any suggestions to look into? "TestMailFlowResult: Failure" My AD (DNS) is being run off of a virtual machine (VMWare), not sure if this is contributing to lag time.

Comment: 2nd update. It looks every time I restart my dns server, the messages in queue get delivered

Comment: Tell me a little more about the topology. Is there a Domain controller in your test environment ? And does it run DNS? The exchange server needs to be a domain member and in the same domain as the DC. So Exchange, DNS, Domain Controller are all in the same domain. Yes? If all that is correct then Run DCDIAG on the domain controller. Something like "DCDIAG /e /c /v /test:DNS >>C:\temp\dcdiag.txt"  Give it 5-10 minutes to run. Fix any test that fails, but don't worry about forwarders. If you can get that to run and pass on everything then you will have reliable DNS.

Comment: Hi Larry, this is solved as of last night. I had to specify the DNS servers IP only, instead ecp was pointed to my dns and my router. After making the switch every works perfectly

Comment: Hi Larry, the new problem I now face is correcting mail flow. I was able to point a public domain successfully with no problem; however, I am not able to send email to other domains. I have configured mx and a records on godaddy, do you have any suggestions ? I can send emails to myself, just not other domains. For example, when I send email to yahoo I get receive a "message delayed" in my inbox

Comment: I have configured the A record like this: Host: Mail.Domain.Com Points To: 1.2.3.4 TTL: 1 Hour. MX Record like this:  Host: @ Points To: Mail.Domain.Com Priority: 0 TTL: 1 Hour. I have enabled ports 80, 443, 25, 110, 143, 587, 995, 993. Sadly there is no luck :(

Comment: Send connector. I was going to suggest you look at the default send connector, but now I read that EX2016 doesn't come with one. Google "Default Send Connector Exchange 2016"  Mustbegeek.com has a step-by-step for you.  You should have two receive connectors and one Send connector when you are done.